# P2P Online Gaming, it is viable?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, mmo, online

I am working on a Peer to Peer based Online Gaming system. I plan on using it for running a decentralized MMORPG in which there are no central servers and traffic is routed evenly among each node/Realm in the network. There are some diagrams and notes that I have for the system and I wanted to know if such a system is actually viable.

https://mega.co.nz/#F!5d8UFaRb!ojwZ0WyDzgFct2IhmdQoZg Diagrams are here.

Essentially this system would be a Mesh Net type network in which people can create their own private realm and then connect it to the network so that other people can play on it. There are two methods to configure the software, 1 you can create your own private realm or 2 you can act as peer for an existing private realm by acting as a mirror for it.

So the more people who connect to the network and play on it, the more stable the network becomes. An individual private realm and its mirror nodes would be called a Realm Cloud. Bit torrent protocol to evenly distribute all traffic to avoid network congestion. IPv6 for global network traffic and DHT for individual realm cloud traffic.

The number of connections can be configured in the client but there must be at least two. The number of maximum connections in theory can be indefinite. End to end encryption keeps all traffic within the network including text and voice chats secure from eavesdropping and garlic routing can prevent tracking.

People can set their own rules and policies for their own realms that they create. If you don't like them then create your own and write the rules the way you like it.

This is still just a basic idea but I just wanted to know if this is an idea that would actually work.

Comment: It could be possible, but synchronisation would be nearly impossible. Say players A, B and C are all playing together on their own realm. B & C go offline and A keeps grinding some more. While A is offline, B comes back on and does some grinding too. Later, C comes online when A & B are offline, and then A & B both join. Who has the "correct" version of the realm to sync against? All clients would believe theirs is correct but they would not agree. This kind of thing (eg BT sync) is fine for static content, but would never work nicely with dynamic data.

Comment: I anticipated the synchronization being an issue which is why I also posted this question to the Network Engineering Site too. Basically I figured that the system would need to support multiple routing tables or have some kind of method to tell the client which realm to route which packets to. I have a few ideas to solve that problem. The use of DHTs specifically organized to each realm cloud or some other kind of identifier to tell the client which realm to route packets to. The other idea was to attach that unique identifier to the end of the data packet that only the client can read.

Comment: The problem becomes easier the more restrictions you put in place. If the world is static (ie player interaction does not change it), and any dynamic entities such as enemies spawn based on where players are all you need to do is synchronise for players with spatial locality. I think FUEL did something like this, where while freeroaming it would find other players in the same area and sync them into your game without having to join a session. (Also, I don't play MMOs so I may be making some assumptions, I'm more used to "normal" multiplayer games wrt synchronisation)

Comment: I've closed this question here because it's too opinion/discussion oriented. But in the future, please don't cross-post questions between SE sites -- that will cause them to get closed as well.

Comment: AFAIK: The game "S4 League" uses P2P.

Comment: Just wanted to say that if you intent do run a decentralized MMORPG you are going to run in hell of a lot trouble. I'm working on distributed MMO framework and I can tell you it's not simple to keep it all synchronized. Using P2P would take you forever to implement correctly if you even manage to do it.